# Free shipping in satchmo

Tags: django, satchmo

I need to add a "free shipping if purchased more than $100" functionality for the Canada Post module in satchmo. Can this be done out of the box, or will I need to make a new shipping module?

Comment: what the.. why does this not have to do with programming? do you even know what satchmo and django are?

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: I've ended up hooking into a satchmo signal and adding a customly created Discount code to the order.

Comment: But by the by.. when I asked this question, there was _no_ code.. unless you wanted me to paste and comment on all the related satchmo code I'd read so far in order to figure out how to do this, which is not a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, to do this I did the following:

```
from product.models import Discount

class AutoDiscount(Discount):
    pass
```

This allows me to define the different discounts in the admin area, and then do this:

```
def check_automatic_discounts(sender, form=None, **kwargs):
    """
    """
    if sender in (CreditPayShipForm, SimplePayShipForm,
                  PaymentContactInfoForm):
        # I probably need to sort these in some specific order
        for discount in AutoDiscount.objects.all():
            if discount.isValid(cart=form.cart,)[0]:
                form.order.discount_code = discount.code
                form.order.save()
                return

signals.form_postsave.connect(check_automatic_discounts)
```

I can add fields to the `AutoDiscount` model and override the `isValid` method if I need more detailed control over which discounts are applied

Comment: Wouldn’t this override any discount code actually entered by the user?

Also, I don’t know if the auto discount code would end up being displayed in email, etc., and could then be reused by the user for other orders.

Comment: Good point. I.. don't really know either, to be honest. This code is over three years old, and I don't remember if and how I tested for these things

Comment: I understand :‑) In the end I did not use discount objects, but put custom code in the cost method of shipper objects to return 0 when needed.